# Assembly print number greater than 9

Tags: assembly, tasm, dosbox

I have to print number greater than 9 in Assembly and I've managed to write this code, but for me it prints "_ _" as an answer. What is wrong?

```
xor ax,ax
mov al,bl
mov bl,0Ah
div bl

mov bl,ah
add bl,48

mov ah,2h
mov dh,offset bl
int 21h

mov bl,al
add bl,48   

mov ah,2h
mov dh,offset bl
int 21h
```

Comment: A place to start would be the docs for [int 21](http://spike.scu.edu.au/~barry/interrupts.html#ah02).  The character to print goes into a register you aren't using.  Also, what do you think `mov dh,offset bl` is supposed to do?

Comment: you don't print numbers, you print ascii-characters (that's why you add 48 before printing, you know?). for numbers > 9, you need to convert it into a string, and print this instead. Google will help you to find one of the hundreds of ready made solutions for this

Comment: So I should do mov ah,9h? I am new to assembly so I can think not properly, but in my opinion, mov dh, offset bl and int 21h should output string. Sorry for my little knowledge...

Comment: `bl` is 8 bit register, it has no memory address, thus it can't have any offset. So you misunderstood what `offset` directive does. Makes me even wonder why the TASM would compile it without error. `mov dh,bl` will copy value from `bl` into `dh`. ... Check the link from David for the `int 21h` service**s** (!) description, and proper arguments, with `ah=2` the content of `dh` is not important.

Comment: Thank you @Ped7g, I'll try that when I come back home